# MySQL row data export to Java Table in Applet?

Tags: java, mysql, applet, export, export-to-excel

I am working on a school project with some guys and need to make an export of the MySQL database table (spiele=games) to the High Score List (GUI based grpahics).
Tried multiple variations but somehow the code doesnt seem correct.

Where do I need to put table code?
How can I modify/paste the rowData and tablecolums correctly?
Can I fill the table rows with the data via "ValueAt"? Or is this something different?

Could I also add another String for a username/ID/studentID ?
Can I also export data like this to excel? or is this another thing?

Thanks!

```
   public void initHighScore() throws IOException {




            Connection conn = null;
            // Notice, do not import com.mysql.jdbc.*
            // or you will have problems!
             try {
                    // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
                    // broken Java implementations
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // handle the error
                }
                        try {
                        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
                        // broken Java implementations

                         conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?useSSL=false","admin","admin");
                        //conn =
                        //         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sys?useSSL=false" +
                        //                                     "user=admin&password=admin");

                         if (conn!= null) {
                             System.out.println("Connection established!");

                        }

                         String query = "SELECT * FROM spiele";

                         // create the java statement
                         Statement st = conn.createStatement();

                         // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                         // iterate through the java resultset

                        String rowData [][] = new String[][]{


                         int li_row = 0;
                            while(rs.next()){
                                table.setValueAt(rs.getDate("tag"),li_row,0);
                                table.setValueAt(rs.getString("gewinnername"),li_row,0);
                                table.setValueAt(rs.getInt("schuesse"),li_row,0);

                                Date userid = rs.getDate("tag");
                                int schuesse     = rs.getInt("schuesse");
                                String name1     = rs.getString("gewinnername");
                                //System.out.println(name1);
                                li_row++;

                            }
                        }

                        frame2 = new JFrame("High Score");
                        String columnNames[] = { "Tag", "Gewinner", "Anzahl Schüsse" };
                        //table = new JTable(   DBHighscore() );







                        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
                        table.setForeground(Color.white);
                        Color background = new Color(0,0,0,0);
                        table.setOpaque(false);
                        table.setBackground(background);




            }
                         st.close();


                         } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // handle any errors
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }







            /*Object rowData [][] = {{ "    Rang    ", "    Punkte  ", "    Matrikelnummer  " },
                { "1", "", "" },{ "", "", "" },{ "", "", "" },{ "", "", "" },{ "", "", "" },{ "", "", "" } };

            */
```

Comment: Please check "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )". This question is missing key information: How are your table defined? What is your expected output? What output are you getting now?

Comment: ah sorry:
 
just got this code from the first version.  
Its not compiling right now because I dont even know, if the code is correct at all :/
 
I also did another version but couldnt manage to actually ADD data from the db to the table
 
this is my table: 
table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
                        table.setForeground(Color.white);
                        Color background = new Color(0,0,0,0);
                        table.setOpaque(false);
                        table.setBackground(background);